# Al enviar correo desde C# no queda en la Carpeta de elementos enviados

Tags: c#, .net

mi problema es el siguiente estoy enviando correo desde un servidor smtp que fue montado propiamente, no es el smtp.live; el envía bien los correos, pero el problema es que no queda en la carpeta de elementos enviados del correo desde el que se envió; alguna solución? muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Lo mas normal es que no se registren, una cosa es un protocolo SMTP y otra cosa un cliente de correo, la verdad ni idea como lograr que se registren en el cliente especificados los correo enviados externametne

Comment: Hola alher93, bienvenido a [es.so], justo como lo menciona el colega bianchi, ayúdanos dando más detalles como: ¿es una aplicación de C#? ¿cómo configuraste tu smtp? ¿revisaste listas negras para saber si no se bloqueó el envío del mail? etc. Agrega todos aquellos detalles técnicos para que podemas saber la mejor manera de ayudarte :)

Answer (score 0):

Esa es una configuración que tiene que ver con tu servidor de correo. En C# sólo se utiliza el protocolo de SMTP para realizar peticiones al servidor de correo y que este realice el envío de los correos solicitados.

Saludos